# What is the minimum value for ESP.deepSleep(n)?

Tags: esp8266, sleep

I noticed that when calling `ESP.deepSleep(1)`, the ESP8266 sometimes does not wake. Why am I entering such a low value? I want to sleep for the minimum amount of time so that I can restart with WiFi back on using `WAKE_RF_DEFAULT` (I previously turned it off with `WAKE_RF_DISABLED` to save power).

I believe that a value of `0` will permanently sleep, but a value of `1` seems to make it sleep unreliably.

To solve this, I used `ESP.deepSleep(1e6)` (1 second), but I was curious to know if there was a known minimum value.

Comment: so, as you've discovered, 1 is too low ... have you tried 2? :p

Comment: Haha, no, I had the initial thought of slowly working my way up, but I would have no idea of knowing if it worked by a fluke or not. A value of `1` seems to work in some cases, but not in others. Would be interesting to learn why! :)

Comment: If the ESP32;s sleep feature is similar to an ESP8266, it is just an internally generated pulse that goes out one pin and into the wake-up pin.  Maybe the implementation is such that setting a delay of 1 doesn't always give the software enough time to setup the processor to wake up after entering sleep mode. My guess is that setting it to 2 will almost if not always work.  But keep in mind the ESP8266 wake up pulse varies a lot with temperature.  So it may be prudent to pick an even longer delay like 4 or 5.

Comment: @st2000 Sounds logical, thanks for the insight!